# Choose multiple branches when performing a build

Tags: teamcity, user-acceptance-testing

We have multiple layers of our products split into different build configurations for continuous integration.  For the sake of this question, let's just say we have a "Front-End CI" build, and a "API CI" build.  The VCS roots are configured to pull in all branches, and triggered to run upon checkin, as should be expected for CI.

Now I have my User Acceptance project, where I use CloudFormation to dynamically spin up servers to which I deploy. I have snapshot dependencies set up for the CI builds mentioned above, and everything works as expected for the default branches on each of the VCS roots and dependencies.  I expect that a feature branch for the front-end may not necessarily necessitate a branch from the default for the API, and the current way I have it setup accounts for that as well.

That's where I begin to have issues.  If I have to branch both the front-end and API, I cannot get TeamCity to do what I want in this regard.  My question is this:  how do I tell Team City to run a UA build using branch "A" from the Front-End CI build config and branch "B" from the API CI build config, where "A" and "B" can be any arbitrary branch?  Currently right now, all branches from both snapshots are shown when I look at the UA build config.  Here's a good picture:

[image]

If I run api-branch, it will always use the default branch from the Front-end CI snapshot.  Same for any branch on the front-end snapshot.  I cannot seem to find a way to specify this in the configuration or when starting a build.

I'm up for just about anything to address this, including build configs that are just cloned off of each other to specify branches the way they're meant to, but I'm just not seeing how I can do that either.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a teamcity template target which monitors both the front end and API repositories and can trigger on changes. This should be one target (and not 2 different targets). Parameterize the branch names so that actual targets have to give the branch name
2. I would suggest creating a mapping of the frontend:api branches in a datastore( file,db,nosql) . Then dynamically create teamcity targets (through REST API) for each new/modified combination and explicitly set the branch names. Once the targets are created they will automatically run whenver there are any changes.